# Возможно ли, реализовать обобщенный метод, получающий все данные из коллекции пользовательских типов, работая с MongoDB C# Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Всем доброго вечера! Работаю с официальным MongoDB C# Driver, версии 2.0. Начиная с этой версии все серьезно поменялось, все методы стали асинхронными, какие-то исчезли, заменились. Поэтому в новых методах ориентируюсь плохо.
Собственно, сама задача примитивная:

Нужно реализовать обобщенный метод, который бы возвращал все элементы коллекции.

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(string collectionName)
    {

        var collection = database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);

        var cursor = collection.FindAll(); //Старая версия драйвера!
        //...
    }
```

Раньше я использовал метод FindAll(), сейчас этого метода больше нет. Есть  FindAsync, или Find, но они все требуют параметров. Это очень неудобно, ведь нужно реализовать обобщенный метод. Конечно для работы с параметрами можно использовать ограничения на T, но это неудобно.

Собственно вопрос в том, возможно ли, используя какие-то методы из MongoDB C# Driver, версии 2.0., реализовать обобщенный метод, получающий все элементы коллекции. Заранее, огромное спасибо!

Comment: А что за параметры передается в новый Find?
Скорее всего это фильтр. Если это и правда фильтр, то выборку всех элементов легко сделать при помощи лямбда-выражения: (a => true), т.е. будет что-то вроде:

collection.Find(a => true);

Comment: @nuts119 Да спасибо огромное! Все заработало, а я просто недодумался